# Tailwind with Angular grid-cols not working

Tags: angular, tailwind-css

This simple code gives me the right result in play.tailwind.com (a grid with two columns) but in my Angular project grid-cols-2 doesn't work. Every other tailwind class works fine.

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
    <div>
        aaaa
    </div>
    <div>
        aaaa
    </div>
    <div>
        aaaa
    </div>
    <div>
        aaaa
    </div>
    <div>
        aaaa
    </div>
    <div>
        aaaa
    </div>
</div>
```

Versions:
Angular: 15
Tailwind: 3.2.7

Any sugestions?

Class grid-cols-2 works in play.tailwind.com but not in my project.
I expect 2 columns, but it's ignoring grid-cols-2 class, resulting in many columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To limit the possibility of errors, does playground happen to [reference a Tailwind CSS file that contains all classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn)
and possibly only generates the CSS classes in its own project that are contained in the project at the time?

If so, was Tailwind run again after the class was inserted?

Otherwise, is the class in the area searched by Tailwind? It would be best to post the tailwind config.
Otherwise you could try the [safelist](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes).

Comment: Thanks! Puting <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script> in header the class works fine!
But I didn't understand why, if I have installed all classes with npm, why I need this reference?

Comment: This only served to find out the Problem. The CDN variant of TailwindCSS I would not recommend for several reasons for a production operation, ALSO because just an advantage of TailwindCSS is that just the required CSS classes are output as CSS file.

For more details I would have to see the config.